# An inconsistency problem between browsers, puzzle me long time

Tags: css, web-standards

**First, the screenshots**

[image: browser-problem]

As you see, although i explicitly described the height, padding-top, etc, there's always a little differece between browsers, how can i make them the same? This problem keep puzzling me and i never find the cause, i even tried delete reset.css i use but still no luck

**Paste related DOM and CSS for reference**

DOM:

```
<div id="menu">
        ...
        <form id="topsearch">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" tabindex="2"></button>
            <input id="s" name="s" type="text" value="SEARCH..." tabindex="1" />
        </form>
</d
```

CSS:

```
#topsearch {
    height:31px;width:205px;
    padding:8px 0 4px;
    background-color:#202020;
    float:right;
}

#topsearch #s {
    height: 17px;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#topsearch button {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border: none;
}
```

**Add the view in Firebug**

[image: viewinfirebug]

Comment: And what is your question? Are there any problems? To be honest, without your description I wouldn't even have noticed any differences.

Comment: you can't easily tell because it is seperated from the whole design, if put back, this problem will become sharp cos it doesn't get aligned with other elements on the page

Comment: can you add different background colors to the elements in the example so we can identify the problem better.. ?s

Comment: screenshot with firebug added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find a solution myself, quite simple, just make the button float left, now appearance are kept same in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `margin: 0` for all elements and see if you still have the same problem. Often  browsers will apply their own margin/padding to different elements.

Comment: I have a globle * {margin:0}, elements listed above all have no other margin-top or margin-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities:

- JavaScript: 
  You could set different values with JavaScript depending on the browser like this: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/
- Conditional HTML: Use the special [`<!--[if IE]>`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) tags to solve the problem at least for Internet Explorer.
- Server side stylesheet switching: Detect the users browser with your server side language and include stylesheets accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified the rest of your CSS I could only test it with default settings in Chrome, Internet Explorer 8, and Mozilla Firefox, but this should look exactly the same across browsers making use of `position: absolute`:

```
#topsearch {
    height: 43px;
    width: 205px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    background-color:#202020;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}

#topsearch #s {
    height: 17px;
    width: 155px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 30px;
    border: 0;
}

#topsearch button {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Apply your preferred styling and be sure to change `top` and `left` positions accordingly.